# Xdebug stops at breakpoint but cannot continue step by step

Tags: visual-studio-code, xdebug

All was working perfectly but today after an update I cannot use Xdebug as normal. Yes, it stops @ breakpoints but cannot continue with step by step mode (f10) in VScode.

These are settings in launch.json:

```
        {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "localSourceRoot": "/home/gfxking/Desktop/CurrentDev/SCRIPTS/DEV",
        "serverSourceRoot": "/var/www/vhosts/dev/httpdocs"
    },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
```

Server output:

```
[root@server ~]# /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php -vPHP 7.1.25 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2018 12:12:21) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2018, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.25, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

50-xdebug.ini on server:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=192.168.1.131
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug.log
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir=/tmp
xdebug.max_nesting_level=200
```

Maybe someone else has experienced this and knows what has suddenly changed .. today?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that mysql function in watch list caused this to not work. Removed watch item and finally runs now!